# jQuery, converting a number to two decimal places

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to use the toFixed() function to convert the screen output of a number to two decimal places. I'm just unsure how to achieve this. I have the following function:

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider({
            value: 100,
            min: <?php echo json_encode($minDeposit); ?>,
            max: <?php echo json_encode($maxDeposit); ?>,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount-deposit" ).val( "" + ui.value );
                totalPayableFunc();
                monthlyPaymentsFunc();
            }
        });
        $( "#amount-deposit" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
```

Currently the number that is displayed has one decimal place, I need it to display to two decimal places.

Thanks

Comment: `$( "#amount-deposit" ).val(Number(ui.value).toFixed(2))`

Comment: Why are you JSON encoding two integer values?

Comment: I'm passing them in from PHP, is this not a sensible way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider({
            value: 100,
            min: <?php echo json_encode($minDeposit); ?>,
            max: <?php echo json_encode($maxDeposit); ?>,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount-deposit" ).val(Number(ui.value).toFixed(2));
                totalPayableFunc();
                monthlyPaymentsFunc();
            }
        });
        $( "#amount-deposit" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
```

Comment: What would be the correct way to also apply this to the second to last line of code in the snippet? thanks